# JavaScript Date() returns the wrong time

Tags: javascript, date

My simple test:

```js
var ds = "2018/2/28 15:59";
console.log(ds);
var da = Date(ds);
console.log(da);
ds = "2018-2-28 15:59";
console.log(ds);
var da = Date(ds);
console.log(da);
```

The results are

```
2018/2/28 15:59  
Thu Feb 01 2018 17:26:57 GMT+0800 (+08)  
2018-2-28 15:59  
Thu Feb 01 2018 17:26:57 GMT+0800 (+08)
```

Even given the time  "2018/2/28 15:59" is in a different time zone, it is still very puzzling as the minutes and seconds are different:  59:00 versus 26:57.  Timezone differences are in multiples of 30 minutes.

Comment: Why don't you use "new Date(...)" instead of just "Date(...)"?   https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp   https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp

Comment: Notice how the date is wrong too. Your argument is being ignored and you would get the same result from a plain `Date()`. (`Date()` acts differently when not used as a constructor, like in `new Date()`. The latter isn’t guaranteed to parse many formats either, though, so just avoid it entirely.)

Comment: Why don't you use moment.js for parsing and dormatting Dates: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Look at your wrist watch. Does it match the result you get?

Comment: Regarding "*Timezone differences are in multiples of 30*", not necessarily. Some are 15 or 45 minutes, e.g. Nepal Standard Time is UTC+05:45 and Chatham Standard Time is UTC+12:45. Once you add "new", your next question will be answered by [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 6):

**You forgot to add `new` before `Date()`.**

This means you were just calling a function called `Date()` which (by default) retuns the current date and time.

```js
var ds = "2018/2/28 15:59";
console.log(ds);
var da = new Date(ds);
console.log(da);
ds = "2018-2-28 15:59";
console.log(ds);
var da = new Date(ds);
console.log(da);
```

---

An addition to AuxTacos answer, the proper way to init. your date:

```
var da = new Date(2018, (2-1), 28, 15, 59); // x-1 because 0=Jan,1=Feb...
console.log(date);
```

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Description): "Invoking JavaScript Date as a function (i.e., without the new operator) will return a string representing the current date and time."

Comment: The second parameter for the "proper way" should be 1 (for February), not 2 (which is March). ;-)

Comment: @RobG thanks. Ive displayed it a little bit different to show better **why**.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [zeropublix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48559513/9029328) (you forgot the `new`), your date strings are invalid. The [proper](https://xkcd.com/1179/) way to encode "15 hours and 59 minutes past the midnight marking the beginning of the 28th day of February, 2018 CE" is `"2018-02-28T15:59Z"`. Your system (and mine) might recognize `"2018/2/28 15:59"` as a valid date string, but that's implementation-dependent and prone to failure. The only format recognized in the specification is [a simplification of ISO 8601](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15).

Comment: And you can also provide each piece of data as a separate argument and avoid all possible ambiguity but, for some reason, it isn't as popular as strings.

Comment: Even some current browsers will not correctly parse "2018-02-28T15:59", the built-in parser should not be used (e.g. Safari 11 treats it as UTC, not local).

Comment: That's correct behavior according to the spec and should be reliable. Granted, it's not ISO 8601 spec, but it's still well-specified.

Comment: @AuxTaco—your comment is ambiguous to me. ISO 8601 extended format without a timezone should be parsed as local according to ECMA-262 (which is consistent with ISO 8601), but Safari get's it wrong, which is further evidence that built-in parsers are unreliable.

Comment: @RobG From ECMA-262, 5.1 Edition: "ECMAScript defines a string interchange format for date-times based upon a simplification of the ISO 8601 Extended Format. The format is as follows: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ", "Z is the time zone offset specified as “Z” (for UTC) or either “+” or “-” followed by a time expression HH:mm", "The value of an absent time zone offset is “Z”."

Comment: Aaaand in version 8, "When the time zone offset is absent, date-only forms are interpreted as a UTC time and date-time forms are interpreted as a local time." ...Neat. Including the time-zone offset should still make it unambiguous.

Comment: @AuxTaco—yes it should, but there are cases where you don't want to include an offset. Date-only formats especially should be treated as local, the last two systems I developed did not want date-only treated as UTC, so we had to implement special date handling because of the crazy TC39 decision to treat them as UTC. Sorry, bit of a sore point…

Answer (score -1):

I try this.

```
var ds = "2018/2/28 15:59"; 
var da = new Date(ds);
```

it gives me Date 2018-02-28T15:59:00.000Z. I got right time and date.

Answer (score -1):

`var da = Date(ds);`
here Date gives the current time even if you pass parameter.

try this.

`var ds = "2018/2/28 15:59";
 var da = new Date(ds);`

which gives 2018-02-28T10:29:00.000Z

Comment: Parsing of a string like "2018/2/28 15:59" is implementation dependent and may or may not produce a Date equivalent to "2018-02-28T10:29:00.000Z". The one I'm currently using doesn't, `new Date("2018/2/28 15:59").toISOString()` returns "2018-02-28T05:59:00.000Z", others might give an invalid Date. :-(